# How to replace a specific value in sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite

I am attempting to replace a specific value within a sqlite3 database. Here is my code so far:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

c = conn.cursor()
name="b"

c.execute("UPDATE user SET money = 3  WHERE idcode LIKE (?)", ('%'+name+'%',))
```

In the database, there are 3 columns 'idcode', 'password' and 'money' i want to be able to update a specific users money.

Comment: That should work. Just make sure you do `c.commit()` after it.

Comment: Just as Barmar says, the UPDATE statement looks valid, so it should work.  But you also say "specific user".  Using the LIKE statement is not specific at all.  You are essentially indicating that you want to update ALL users with `idcode` that has a `b` in it anywhere.  If you want to update a specific user, then you should probably just use `WHERE idcode = ?` and pass the exact value.